# Old Android versions browsers do not have some JS functions?

Tags: javascript, android, legacy

Having tested an app with a webview containing a html file on a Oreo device, everything works fully. However, when using a Kitkat device (emulator), I am getting the error `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection: "Object function Object() { [native code] } has no method 'entries'"`.

This was ostensibly due to me having used `Object.entries()` in the html. Is there any way to work around this? The Browser version on the Kitkat emulator is 4.4.2-4729339 and the emulator is the default emulator on Android Studio.

Comment: well it sounds like it is running an old version of JavaScript so you would have to use a polyfill to make it work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make new functions work in older browsers you can use so called `Polyfills` those are mostly to find on github or on Mozilla Developer Network.

What you are looking for is a `Object.entries()` polyfill:

```
if (!Object.entries)
  Object.entries = function( obj ){
    var ownProps = Object.keys( obj ),
        i = ownProps.length,
        resArray = new Array(i); // preallocate the Array
    while (i--)
      resArray[i] = [ownProps[i], obj[ownProps[i]]];

    return resArray;
  };
```

(Code taken from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries#Polyfill)

In general I recommend you to use [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) where you can check what browser supports which function.